# cmake connot find mysqlclient.so

Tags: mysql, cmake

It's where mysqlclient.so located

```
[dbn@hecs-137331 mysql]$ pwd
/usr/lib64/mysql
[dbn@hecs-137331 mysql]$ ls
INFO_BIN  libmysqlclient.so  libmysqlclient.so.21       plugin
INFO_SRC  libmysqlClient.so  libmysqlclient.so.21.1.26
```

And this is how my CMakeLists.txt include the lib

```
target_include_directories(main PUBLIC "usr/lib64/mysql")
include_directories("usr/lib64/mysql")                               
target_link_libraries(main mysqlclient)
```

This is the error message

```
[dbn@hecs-137331 build]$ make
[ 14%] Built target zlog
[ 23%] Built target buffer
[ 47%] Built target http
[ 61%] Built target pool
[ 80%] Built target server
[ 90%] Built target timer
[ 95%] Linking CXX executable bin/main
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make:109: bin/main] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:213: CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

I just install mysql by 'sudo yum install mysql' so There is no file named '*mysqlConfig.cmake*' and i dont use *find_package*

Currently,
`link_directories("usr/lib64/mysql")`
`target_link_libraries(main mysqlclient)`
`link_directories("usr/lib64/mysql")`
all of above cannot find the libmysqlclient.so and show the message `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient`

And I also Tried to copy the lib to the `/usr/bin`dirctory. It doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you meant to use [`link_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/link_directories.html) somewhere in there. And that path is an absolute path, so it should be prefixed with a slash. Ex. `link_directories("/usr/lib64/mysql")`.

Also, I don't see the point in your `*_include_directories` command calls, since from your `ls` output, it doesn't look like there is anything in there that you'd want to `#include`.

Note: I'm not sure if it's a great idea to be hardcoding machine-specific paths into your CMake project config.